# How to add passed value to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ado.net

I'm practicing on WebApplication in ASP.NET C#

I have created **Product Page** in that page I have created gridview with data coming from the database also there is the button called Edit in each row. It will take you to **Update Page** with that row data. and it will put the values in textbox accordingly.

[image: Image of Product Page]

There are text fields and drop box in **Update page**, but when i make change to data and click on update button, the data doesn't update in database.

[image: Image of Edit Page]

**Product.aspx**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication5.Product
{
    public partial class Product1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string pid = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
            Response.Redirect("UpdateProduct.aspx?Product_ID=" + pid);
        }
    }
}
```

**UpdateProduct.aspx**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebApplication5.Product
{
    public partial class UpdateProduct : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
          String myquery = "Select * from Product where pro_id=" + Request.QueryString["Product_ID"];
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = myquery;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                txtpid.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pro_id"].ToString();
                txtpname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pro_name"].ToString();

                txtpprice.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pro_price"].ToString();
                txtpq.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pro_qty"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
            con1.Open();
            string sql ="UPDATE Product set pro_name='"+txtpname.Text.ToString()+"',cat_name='"+DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()+"',pro_price='"+txtpprice.ToString()+"',pro_qty='"+txtpq.ToString()+"'where pro_id='"+txtpid.Text.ToString()+"'";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql,con1);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("Updated!");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the ProductUpdatePage Button1_Click method, what are the values of your text fields?

Comment: unikl eaaa.. ist it?

Comment: check the sql value in the Button1_Click event and see all the necessary data is coming or not?

Answer (score 0):

Please make try catch block  with SQLcatch(SqlException ex), and try to use property's. Also you have nice tool in MSSQL, it's called "SQL server profiler".

Answer (score 0):

Check this : pro_qty='"+txtpq.ToString()+"'--give me space---where pro_id

You don't have space between filed and where clause, give one space after pro_qty and where, your query dosen't execute and you don't see error output, because you don't use all tools.